# How to compare elements in multiple lists

Tags: list, compare

Lets say we have a list that is comprised of a range of numbers:

```
list_1 = [] # all numbers between a range


for num in range(0,1000):
    if num > 0:
        list_1.append(num)
```

Now we want to seperate some numbers from this list, for example, primes:

```
list_2 = [] # all prime numbers in list_1

for num in list_1:
   if num > 1:
       for i in range(2,num):
           if (num % i) == 0:
               break
       else:
           list_2.append(num)
```

Now we want to seperate the list even further, and we notice that prime numbers end in either a 1, 3, 7, or 9. So we tell our program to seperate the primes that end in a certain digit:

```
list_3 = [] # all prime numbers in list_1 that end in the last digit 1
list_4 = [] # all prime numbers in list_1 that end in the last digit 3
list_5 = [] # all prime numbers in list_1 that end in the last digit 7
list_6 = [] # all prime numbers in list_1 that end in the last digit 9

for num in list_2:
    lastdigit = int(repr(num)[-1])
    if lastdigit == 1:
        list_3.append(num)
    elif lastdigit == 3:
        list_4.append(num)
    elif lastdigit == 7:
        list_5.append(num)
    elif lastdigit == 9:
        list_6.append(num)
```

What we want to do is to define a function that compares the elements of list_2 with list_3 through list_6. The purpose would be to create uniquely named lists that group the primes from list_2 into list that begin and end with groups of the same digit. For instance if we run the code we see:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997]
```

We can see on this list that there are prime numbers that end in the same digit and have another number ending in the same digit for instance 181, 191.

If we look at the list further down we can see another instance where 241, 251.

What we want our list to look like is:

```
list1_1 = [181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251]
```

And we want to do this for all numbers in our list of primes. How do we go about doing that? I'm new to python and just trying to understand how to manipulate variables and lists and to compare information between lists for the purpose of computation in number theory. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks Maciej, my first post, I'll try to not do that again

Comment: I don't really understand it all that well, but is the enumerate function what I'm looking for? The idea I'm working with requires me to compare two elements of a list which are next to each other and satisfy a condition, namely that the last digits are the same. I noticed the next() function attached to the enumerate fuction, but don't know how I would call on the objects in the list since i want to iterate over the whole list. I'm going to do some more reading,  but if anyone can at least point me in a direction or confirm that I'm on the right track it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'm planning to use a for loop to iterate over the list, then create two temporary variables inputting the number and the number in the index + 1 in the two variables. checking the last digit of each to test that they match and if so to check their index from list_2 against each other, if the number equals 1 then I would store the smallest number as the value for a permanent variable, repeat the process until i find the next pair and storing the largest number as the secound variable. I want to then use the two var as the range for a new list, named for recall later.